# meta programming to include module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, metaprogramming

I'm using ruby on rails and I currently have code

```
if level == "Grad"
  include Grad
else
  include Undergrad
```

Where level is a string that say either "Grad" or "Undergrad"

I want to use meta programming to include the correct module without the if statement

something like this.

```
send :include, level
```

How do I do this. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include "#{level}".constantize`. Does this work for you?

Comment: Great, but from your answer I just simplify it to  include level.constantize

Comment: I mean why do you need the "#{level}" when you can just use level